# Converting video with ffmpeg from a script not in the root folder

Tags: php, ajax, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert videos, create thumbnails etc.

I made the below function to convert a video and when I run it in a script in the root folder it converts ok.

However, I am using ajax to upload the video and the script is located /ajax/upload-video.php and when I run it in that folder it fails to convert.

I have tried sending the $src and $dest up with ../ before the filenames to go back a folder but it isn't working.

Can anybody help?

Do I need to add something to the $command line to tell it to go back a folder?

These are the variables being used in the function:

```
$ffmpegpath = 'ffmpeg.exe';
$src = 'videos/video1.wmv';
$dest = 'videos/video1.mp4';
```

I have tried:

```
$ffmpegpath = 'ffmpeg.exe';
$src = '../videos/video1.wmv';
$dest = '../videos/video1.mp4';
```

And the function:

```
function convert_video($src, $dest) {

    global $ffmpegpath;

    if (!file_exists($src)) {

        echo '<p>The file does not exist</p>';

    } else {

        $command = "$ffmpegpath -i $src $dest";

        @exec($command, $ret);

        if (!file_exists($dest)) {

            echo '<p>The file failed to create</p>';

        } else {

            if (filesize($dest)==0) {

                echo '<p>The file created but has not filesize</p>';

            } else {

                echo '<p>File Created Successfully</p>';

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i would suspect one of these three variables is wrong: `$ffmpegpath` or `$src` or  `$dest` we dont know your server file structure so you will have to dump them out and check them your self

Comment: @nogad I have updated my answer with the variables. When running the script in the ajax folder if I send $src up without the ../ it fails at the "The file does not exist" stage but with the ../ it fails at the "The file failed to create" stage.

Comment: i would try the full server path for all 3 variables

Comment: @nogad Thanks that did the trick. I had tried the full server path for $src and $dest but not for $ffmpegpath and it worked as soon as I changed that. Thank you for your help.